# Why is my input field uneditable?

Tags: html, css, firefox

I'm building a web page with many mixed-in libraries: jQuery, Bootstrap, a number of other services' scripts, and so on.  I'm using an earlier (modified) version of the [Really Simple Color Picker](https://github.com/laktek/really-simple-color-picker), and the input control is uneditable, but only in Firefox.  In Chrome, Safari, and Internet Explorer, the field is editable.

I can find nothing in the code that is making the field uneditable.  In Firefox, I can see in the firebug panel that the `.uneditable-input` CSS styles are being applied, but the element itself has no classes, either in the original HTML, the HTML view, or the DOM view.

Some other attributes that seem related in the DOM view are:

```
 className ""
 contentEditable "inherit"
 disabled false
 hidden false
 indeterminate false
 readOnly false
 required false
```

What could make my input uneditable, and why in only one browser?

One more twist: the input field itself is actually inserted onto the page with jQuery code in the color picker library.

I would love to include code, but the page is very large with a dozen dependencies, I'm looking now for ideas about what kinds of things can make a field uneditable so that I can hunt for causes.  I know it's not great to not include code, I will work on whittling it down.

Comment: Can you make a http://jsfiddle.net/ demo or otherwise link to a test case?

Comment: 82K rep and no relevant code in the question? That's gotta be some sort of record.

Comment: Sorry about not having code to share, I've updated the question: I'm whittling it down at the moment, and asking here about potential causes.

Comment: @NedBatchelder: For all I can tell, there might be an overlay div stretching of your input, making it unclickable. I'm afraid we need to see all relevant code (hopefully a test-case) in order to help you with this one :)

Comment: The `.uneditable-input` classname is part of Twitter Bootstrap library, so I'd concentrate in this direction. With the sparse information provided so far it's impossible to post a fitting answer. Stack Overflow isn't the right place for lists, guesses and endless discussion.

Comment: FWIW, I had a similar problem with jQuery and Boostrap. My input field was styled to "float: left" and for some reason that was preventing me from being able to type in it. I removed that style and  added a wrapper div around it to which I applied that style and everything worked out. Weird.

Comment: Check -moz-box-sizing: border-box;  I had the same problem and have narrowed the problem down to that, when I unset -moz-box-sizing, I can edit the input

Answer (score 2):

What you want to do is install Firebug, and examine the DOM element in that. It will show you any customized CSS properties, and you can check/uncheck them one by one. You will likely find the one that's causing the problem quickly.

[image]

If it's not actually disabled, but you can't interact with it, you can also see that in Firebug. Just use the inspect by mouse click feature, and it will show you which DOM element is on top of it, and what it's dimensions are.

[image]

Comment: That's... kinda what he already did...

Comment: @ChaseSiebet: Thanks.  As I noted in the question, I've examined the element in the HTML pane, the CSS pane, and the DOM pane.  I've included what I thought might be relevant info.  Is there something else I've overlooked?